# Sklearn RandomizedSearchCV suddenly stuck

Tags: performance, parameters, scikit-learn, grid-search

I tried to do a RandomizedSearchCV for a SVM model but it seems to take forever. It works fine for KNN. I found the process stuck somewhere after finishing certain tasks. The below is my code:

```
# SVC Parameter Tuning
svc_params = {'C': np.power(10, np.arange(-5., 1.)), 
              'kernel': ['rbf', 'linear', 'sigmoid', 'poly'],
              'degree': np.arange(3, 21), 
              'coef0' : np.linspace(0, 1, 100), 
              'shrinking': [True, False], 
              'class_weight' : ['balanced', None]}

svc = RandomizedSearchCV(SVC(), 
                         svc_params, 
                         cv = 5, 
                         scoring = 'roc_auc', 
                         n_jobs = 128, 
                         n_iter = 100,
                         verbose = 2)
```

after some results, the process stuck.

```
[CV]  kernel=poly, C=0.0001, degree=20, coef0=0.848484848485, 
shrinking=True, class_weight=balanced, total=  11.1s
[CV]  kernel=poly, C=0.0001, degree=20, coef0=0.848484848485, 
shrinking=True, class_weight=balanced, total=  11.0s
[CV]  kernel=poly, C=0.0001, degree=20, coef0=0.848484848485, 
shrinking=True, class_weight=balanced, total=  11.5s
```

I am really out of clue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How large is your data? For svm, normalized/standardized data works best. Is your data pre-processed for that?

Comment: @VivekKumar My data size is about 900 with 9 features. Most of them are categorical value.

Comment: Can you post a link to your dataset ?

Comment: I am using the data from kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data)

Comment: I reviewed the doc of sklearn again, and I think it might be caused by the setting of degree. It works well after I muted it. It could be caused by having a high degree and poly kernel, then all the data points might collapse to a crowded space.